# Compress working directory purely using bash regex

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash, unix

I want to know the best way to compress the current working directory so that only the last directory's full name is visible. Let me give an example:

```
$ echo $PWD
/Users/mac/workshop/project1/src
```

I want to be able to do **bash regex replacement** operations on it such that I can get `~/w/p/src`

I can obtain the first part of getting the leading ~ by doing ${PWD/#$HOME/\~}

```
$ echo ${PWD/#$HOME/\~}
~/workshop/project1/src
```

What other regex operations can I do (is it possible to chain the regex operators?) so that I get the following

```
$ echo ${PWD/#$HOME/\~} ...
~/w/p/src
```

Note that I need to do only using bash i.e. no sed, awk, grep etc.

The intention for this is so that, I can set the PROMPT value based on bash i.e.

in my `.bashrc`, I want to:

```
export PROMPT=${PWD/#$HOME/\~}...
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it, `bash` doesn't have a built-in regular expression replacement operation. It has `${var/pattern/replacement}`, but pattern is just a wildcard, not a regexp, and there's no way to copy parts of the match into the replacement.

Comment: ..."bash regex replacement"? Eh? Parameter expansions use fnmatch-style expressions, not regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do-able in just bash, but not as simple as you'd like:

```
$ squashPWD() {     
    local pwd parts part 
    IFS=/ read -ra parts <<< "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"
    for part in "${parts[@]:0:${#parts[@]}-1}"; do 
        pwd+="${part:0:1}/"
    done
    echo "$pwd${parts[-1]}"
}

$ pwd
/home/jackman/tmp/adir/foo

$ squashPWD 
~/t/a/foo

$ cd /usr/local/share/doc/fish/

$ squashPWD 
/u/l/s/d/fish
```

---

If you don't need bash:

```
squashPWD() { perl -pe 's/^$ENV{HOME}/~/; s{([^/])[^/]*(?=/)}{$1}g' <<<"$PWD"; }
```

---

Either way, your prompt can be something like:

```
PS1='\u@\h:$(squashPWD) \$ '
```

Comment: I'd suggest turning off glob expansion before the `set -- $pwd`, or doing something like `local -a pieces; IFS=/ read -r -a pieces; set -- "${pieces[@]}"` (the last of that being optional, if you want to use `$@` elsewhere in the function) to split it into an array more safely.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't **need** to be all bash, you can use a function in your `bashrc` or `bash_profile` and thus use sed or awk.  You can put something like this in your `bashrc`:

```
short() {
    local short_path=$(echo "$PWD" | sed -E 's!/(.)[^/]*!/\1!g')
    local last_dir=${PWD##*/}
    echo "${short_path::-1}${last_dir}" # remove last character (1st character of last directory, and just append the last directory)
}

PS1='$(short) '
```

Keep in mind I don't think I replace your `$HOME` directory with `~`, but you know how to do that :)

Comment: Oops, you just wiped out your $PATH variable. Don't use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES

Comment: Also, if you don't declare your variables `local`, they're all globals, so not scoped to the function

Comment: Also, why `eval "short"` rather than just `PS1=$(short)$ `?

Comment: Also, quote your expansions, or you'll have unusual behaviors if a character found inside the current path is also in IFS. Look at what happens to this code if `IFS=/`, for instance; making it `echo "${short_path:-1}${last_dir}"` prevents that.

Comment: Also, using the `function` keyword makes your code needlessly nonportable -- this would work with `/bin/sh`, unless I'm missing something, if you just defined it `short() {` without that preceding keyword.

Comment: ...also, invoking an external tool such as `sed` or `awk` every single time a prompt is printed is a pretty big performance penalty. I'd expect this to be much slower than glenn's approach.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for your suggestions, I agree with them and have edited my answer.  Perhaps performance isn't the most efficient, but my main point of the solution was to tell OP that doing it all in bash or one line isn't a requirement like they thought.  Rather, you can still make a function in your `bashrc` and do what you need to do.